# XSLT 1.0 using the number function

Tags: xml, json, xslt

I am using the `number()` function in my XSLT markup in order to translates values, in this case odds from a casino, into JSON. Example XML looks like the following:

```
<Casino ClientID="116" Name="5Dimes">-116</Casino>
<Casino ClientID="104" Name="BOVADA">+104</Casino>
```

My markup looks like the following:

```
"line": <xsl:call-template name="odds_check_tpl"><xsl:with-param name="odds_field" select="text()" /></xsl:call-template>
```

And the `odds_check_tpl` is written like this:

```
   <xsl:template name="odds_check_tpl">
      <xsl:param name="odds_field" />
        <xsl:choose>
           <xsl:when test="string($odds_field) != 'NaN'"><xsl:value-of select="number($odds_field)" /></xsl:when>
           <xsl:otherwise>"Not Available Yet"</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
```

The problem I'm having is that when I attempt to parse `-116` this comes out perfectly. For `+104` however, I get a `NaN`. I'm guessing the `number()` function treats `-` as negatives but gets tricked out when an explicit `+` is put in front of a number. Is there a way to work around this so I can treat these values as numbers in my JSON vs having to use a string?

Comment: I don't see a problem running it. For both I get proper results. Moreover, the condition "string($odds_field) != 'NaN'" is meaningless. It's same as checking "'-116' != 'NaN'" which is always true. Correct one would be string(number($odds_field)) != 'NaN' as this condition would convert the string to number, the output to "string" and then compare with 'NaN'.

Comment: @LingamurthyCS You are probably running a XSLT 2.0+ processor. Try it with Xalan or Saxon 6.

Comment: Oh yeah.. I don't have XSLT1.0 processor handy, right now.

Comment: One solution is to use `substring` and remove the `+`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you simply **translate** the + sign out, for example:

```
<xsl:call-template name="odds_check_tpl">
    <xsl:with-param name="odds_field" select="translate(., '+', '')" />
</xsl:call-template>
```

Then, assuming odds cannot be zero, you can simplify your test to:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="number($odds_field)">
        <xsl:value-of select="$odds_field" />
    </xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>"Not Available Yet"</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

---

### Edit

If you want to preserve the + sign at the output, then call the template without translating:

```
<xsl:call-template name="odds_check_tpl">
    <xsl:with-param name="odds_field" select="." />
</xsl:call-template>
```

and do the test as:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="number(translate($odds_field, '+', ''))">
        <xsl:value-of select="$odds_field" />
    </xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>"Not Available Yet"</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

--
Let me just stress again that this assumes odds are not supposed to be zero (as this is not at all obvious from the examples given); in such case the result will be ""Not Available Yet".

Comment: Is there a way to re-add the `+` here though? Works fine for `-`

Answer (score 1):

You can strip the `+` before converting it. This will create a variable `$number` containing either a number or `NaN`:

```
<xsl:variable name="number">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="substring($odds_field, 1, 1) = '+'">
            <xsl:value-of select="number(substring($odds_field, 2))" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="number($odds_field)" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

You can then use it in your test:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$number != 'NaN'">
        <xsl:value-of select="$number" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>"Not Available Yet"</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: Slightly confused in how I'd rewrite my template to work both of those tests in. Am I replacing the template completely with one or both of the above?

Comment: The second block replaces the contents of the xsl:`choose` in your original template. The first block defines the `number` variable, so you can place it before the `xsl:choose`.

Comment: But take a look at the answer by @michael.hor257k. It's much simpler.